# freeze on purple screen when installing 14.04

Tags: 14.04, screen, freeze, acer, libpurple

I've tried to install 6 different variants of ubuntu today and failed everytime always the same problem.
It boots up, I'm greeted with a screen that asks if I want to test or install ubuntu (there were probably more options) (I've tried both multiple times on different versions) it goes through a black screen with alot of words than reaches the purple screen with an ubuntu logo and 5 grey dots, one by one the dots turn red, then nothing.

my computer:
acer aspire 5560
4gb ram 
The processor is an AMD A8-3500M APU.

Comment: Hit F12 while the boot animation is showing. It should disappear and show the kernel log, where you can look for hang ups or errors.

Comment: Didn't do anything but leave a black screen.

Comment: Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: In the bootloader, press e, then go in line stating kernel, remove quiet and splash from the kernel parameters and press ctrl+x  and it will get stuck at some point, so you will know what the error is, which you can post in your main post.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with QEMU. The trick for me was that I was using the flag `-cpu host,level=9`. I had remembered that I had issues with this in the past, and changes to `-cpu host` and things resolved themselves.